# Suggestions for an out-of-core sparse solver

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, hpc

I have a sparse $2\times10^5$ by $2\times10^5$ matrix with $3.2\times10^9$ non-zero elements.

I want a sparse solver with out-of-core functionality. I have attempted to use Intel's `MKL pardiso`, with a varying degree of success. For smaller problems, it is stellar, but for the problem size above, it is taking a huge amount of `RAM` (even with the out-of-core enabled), presumably during fill-in reducing ordering stage.

The `intel` staff has been incredibly helpful with debugging several problems, but I feel that it might be prudent to try a different solver.

Is there any good reference comparing the performance of solvers for big problems?

Comment: Does your problem has a structure that could be exploited ? You used a sparse direct solver, would it be possible to use an iterative solver instead ? (conjugate gradient), that has smaller memory requirements.

Comment: The matrices in question have very little structure. They are not symmetric, nor diagonal. However, the non-zeros for each row are contiguous (i.e. there are no zeros interrupting a stretch of values). That's the strongest claim I can make about the structure.

Comment: and did you try an iterative solver ? (GMRES or BiCGSTAB for instance), with compressed row storage, it may fit in RAM. Do you have an idea of the conditioning ?

Comment: I did not try any iterative solvers - I suppose that is a reasonable next step. I would need to run some calculations to figure out the condition numbers for the problem. My guess is that they will vary wildly with the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go with a direct solver, you may consider the following options:

- Intel MKL Pardiso, which you have already tried
- MUMPS, that is another very popular choice for parallel direct solvers and has an out-of-core capability
- [HSL](http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/), free for academic use, consider HSL_MA78, sparse out-of-core solver

Several years ago, I added to my collection the following paper that compares the performance of those three libraries for Navier-Stokes FEM:

- [Mandhapati P. Raju and Siddhartha Khaitan, "High Performance Computing Using Out-of-Core Sparse Direct Solvers", *Int. J. Math. Computat. Phys. Electr. Comput. Eng.*, vol. 3, no. 9, Sep. 2009](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/376e/18e903f39532fb9976ec4e9e95160da251c6.pdf). This is a questionable publisher [WASET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Academy_of_Science,_Engineering_and_Technology), so take this paper with an extra grain of salt; however, I haven't found anything criminal with that particular paper myself.